# How do I reduce/compress the size of a non-text PDF with minor loss of quality?

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I have lots of PDF documents which take a lot space in the DB because they are scans of text documents with handwritten annotations. Each page is actually a JFIF image.

I tried a command from a similar SO question which resulted in a considerable gain in size (11Mb to 1Mb) but also a considerable loss of quality as the text becomes very blury and hard to read:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dEncodeColorImages=true -sOutputFile=/tmp/document-1.pdf /tmp/document.pdf
```

How do I reduce the size of a my PDF with minor loss of quality ?

Comment: Define 'minor loss of quality'. You can see that the default settings affect the output, If you read the documentation (https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/VectorDevices.htm#COMMON) you can see what controls are affected by the '/screen' settings. You can then modify the controls yourself instead of using the default settings, which will give you finer control.

Comment: I think the 'ebook' profile is my definition of  'minor loss of quality' (might not be yours)

Answer (score 1):

From here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018211/8315843

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfimage8 -r150 -sOutputFile=/tmp/document-1.pdf /tmp/document.pdf
```

The profile 'ebook' also uses the resolution of 150dpi among lots of other parameters :

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile=/tmp/document-1.pdf /tmp/document.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try k2pdfopt.

k2pdfopt -mode copy.

It sticks to older compression algorithms, because of compatibility constraints, so it may increase pdf file size, but it usually reduces pdf fie size and almost always reduces loading time.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer because I also searched a lot for a **oneliner** that would allow me to `downscale` the scanned images and set the `DPI` of the resulting `pdf`.

The answer from Sybuser is correct and will produce the wanted effect, but I was looking for something more than a predefined list of SETTINGS.

This is the resource I recommend: [follow link](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Output_resolution) to understand what possibilities are offered by `GhostScript`.

I used the following combination of switches:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfimage8 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -r150 -q -o output.pdf Clopotele-Hemingway.pdf
```

to reduce 9 pages of a scanned book from `2.3 M` :
[image: original]

down to `660 K`:
[image: compressed]

| Original | "Compressed" (pdfimage8 dDownScaleFactor=2 DPI: 150 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: original] | [image: compressed] |

All the necessary details and more you can find at the [official documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Output_resolution) of `GhostScript`, by experimenting with the three switches, you can tune in to a setting that best suits your needs:

> `-sDEVICE`=pdfimage8
> `-dDownScaleFactor`=2
> `-r`150

Happy compressing!